# Accessing location field in Drupal 7, via hosting entity object and wrapper

Tags: drupal-7

I'm using Location module (particularly its Location CCK part) with Drupal 7. Added location field 'field_location' to User (as an example of hosting entity), and initialized location values for test users in user edit interface. However, I'm unable to access location data of the current user:

```
global $user;
$user_id = $user->uid;

$loc = $user->field_location;
```

or:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user_id);
$loc = $wrapper->field_location;
```

The statements with $loc don't work for object and wrapper (while both user object and wrapper are initialized successfully). Same for:

```
$loc = $wrapper->field_location[0];
$loc = $wrapper->field_location->raw();
```

I've read a number of posts on this topic, however haven't found a workable solution, would appreciate insights on this.

Answer (score 3):

The location module, by itself, does not support the Entity API/Metadata Wrapper out-of-box. However, it is packaged with the Location Entity module, which will enable it for entity api support.

Once enabled,

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user_id);
$loc = $wrapper->field_location->value();
```

Works as expected.

If you want a quick workaround, you can also do:

```
$user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user_id);
$raw_user = $user_wrapper->raw();
$loc = $raw_user->field_location['und'][0];
```

This isn't elegant, but it's a solution without additional modules. Take your pick.